# Distributing Windows environment with application

Tags: windows, environment, live-cd

I am interested in distributing an application that will need to have an integrated Windows environment included with it. This environment would be something like [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/).

Basically the application needs to create bootable media with a minimal Windows subsystem included on that media that can be inserted in a system with no operating system on it. Then the application would run in this environment.

Any ideas on how to best accomplish this, and the licensing required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need [WinPE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(WS.10).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the license allows you to do that.  However, you can distribute your software and instructions on how to incorporate it into a bootable CD.